# Why sid required in 'KILL SESSION' (Oracle SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle, sessionid

I have exam question and can't find answer. Why `sid` is mandatory required to perform `KILL SESSION` command?
`KILL SESSION` syntax: `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,session#[@inst_id]' [IMMEDIATE];`
Where **sid** is a 'unique' session identifier. Unique in quotes because it is unique in **current moment**, Oracle server can have, for example, session some sid, but after this session is over, this sid can be used for other session. `Sid` is analogy `pid` in OS.
**Session#** is a **serial** session number; it is a session counter. Server clear the counter at DB startup. So, session# is a really **unique identifier** for session.

I don't understand why `sid` is mandatory for `KILL SESSION` command. I think, it is possible to use `session#` only.

Thanks.

Comment: I've always used SERIAL# rather than SESSION#. ie ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#'; as derived from V$SESSION

Comment: Yes, `@inst_id` is optional and used in RAC servers only. `IMMEDIATE` is optional too; it used for gracefully shutdown session. I don't understand why `sid` is mandatory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it! Sequence for `serial#` is cyclic. Numbers will be reused after 2 billions logins if `int` used, or after 32k if `short` used. So, using `serial#` without anything else doesn't provide **really unique** enumerating.
But `sid` is unique at a moment. So, pair `sid,serial#` is **really unique**.
You can't use `serial#` or `sid` to manage sessions, you should use it in a pair.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6):

You need the SID and SERIAL#. The oracle [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a67790/ch3.htm#9225) has this to say:

> **SID**   Session identifier
>
> **SERIAL#**   Session serial number. Used to identify uniquely a session's
> objects. Guarantees that session-level commands are applied to the
> correct session objects if the session ends and another session begins
> with the same session ID

So while a SID is unique, it can be re-used. So I guess the addition of a SERIAL# would ensure you don't kill a newly connected session that happens to use the same SID of what you were trying to kill (if they disconnected already before you executed the command).

UPDATE in response to Jury's comment:

I can't say why it is implemented like this, just my understanding of the implementation as per the documentation:  SID is re-usable, the SERIAL# within a SID is not. So, as an example:

- [1,1] JOE connects and is assigned SID 1, SERIAL# 1
- JOE disconnects
- [1,2] TOM connects and is assigned SID 1 (reuse), but SERIAL# is incremented to 2
- [2,1] SUSAN connects and is assigned SID 2, SERIAL# 1

Why this implementation? Keeps numeric sizes manageable, perhaps? Minimize contention? Reuse of already allocated resources (represented by the SID)? I don't know.

Comment: I have know it. You are right. `Serial#` is more unique as `sid`. As unique as `sid` not needed to identify session....but it required for `KILL SESSION`. Why?

Comment: @Jury Can you link to some Oracle documentation that indicates that SERIAL# is unique across all SIDs?

Comment: Good question...because I have heard it from teacher :)  I found following [After  2,000,000,000 (2 billion) logins -- the numbers will be reused](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:65212348056)

Comment: So, after 2^31 - 1 logins, session# will get initial value (0 or 1). If it true, pair `sid,session#` seems **absolutely** unique. Interesting...

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old topic, but I wanted to point out that serial# by itself isn't even close to a unique identifier, even at a particular point in time.

```
SQL> select serial#, count(*) from v$session group by serial#;

   SERIAL#   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
         1         15
       983          1
         2          1
       505          1
         5          2
      7076          1
         7          2
        58          1
         3          3
         9          1
     22160          1

11 rows selected.
```

Out of the 29 sessions I have in my database currently, there are only 11 distinct serial#s.

EDIT: And this is a single instance database. In a RAC environment, you need to include the instance ID to get a truly unique session, from what I understand (I've never personally worked with a RAC database).